# download as archive in firefox not getting full file name

Tags: php, http-headers, mozilla, php-ziparchive, content-disposition

I am using `ZipArchive` library for downloading contents as archive.
The problem is that the archived file not getting full name that as given, its ending at first space. eg: if i am giving the file name as "new file.zip"

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename = new file.zip');
```

While googling i found that just putting the quoted file name solves the problem. So i tried this:

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename = 'new file.zip'");
```

but nothing changes, while downloading the file name changes to "new.zip", what i have to get is "new file.zip"

The problem is only with firefox

Comment: Have a try escaping the blank in the name (a blank in a technical file name never is a good idea...): `filename = new\ file.zip`.

Comment: nothing changed, now the file name getting as new\.zip

Comment: You should accept the answer if your query has been effectively resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the content type as `application/zip, application/octet-stream` before you make the file download and include the `filename` in double quotes.

```
// We'll be outputting a ZIP
header('Content-Type: application/zip, application/octet-stream');

// It will be called new file.zip
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new file.zip"');
```

If you pass the variable filename, that could have spaces:

```
header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" . $fileName ."\"");
```

Note that the `filename` is surrounded by `double quotes`, per [RFC 2231](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2231.txt). This allows for the use of extended characters within the filename (i.e., international characters).

Comment: a slight change:
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."\"");

Comment: The answer is only partly correct; the change to Content-Type is incorrect: it's not needed, it's invalid (you can't specify two types), and it defeats the point of declaring the type in the first place.

Comment: @JulianReschke Shouldn't we inform the browser the type of content we are about to send, although yes it is not necessary?

Comment: Yes, you should. But "application/zip, application/octet-stream" is not a content type, it's a syntax error :-)

Comment: @JulianReschke So it should just be `Content-Type: application/zip`?